# ORA-04068: PLSQL stored procedure some calls are failed and some calls are passed

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, jdbi, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to execute oracle stored procedure from my application and connecting ORACLE database. I noticed, same connections call get passed and some connection throwing exception as below:

```
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
ORA-04061: existing state of package body "USER.PKG_MY_PACKAGE" has been invalidated
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package body "USER.PKG_MY_PACKAGE"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program being called: "USER.PKG_MY_PACKAGE"
ORA-06512: at line 34
```

I referred some stack overflow post and we can fix in DB side. But DB side I don't have access to fix this issue(i.e. production) is there any way to fix from application side. I am using JDBI-Datasource-connection pooling in my java code. If I restart my lower environments and works fine. But, I can't restart the production environment each and every time. Please let me know, how to fix this issue from my application side.

Comment: You need to check who is fiddling with those packages or any dependent objects in production. It is not something which you fix from application.

Comment: What you can do is the following (by the time this thing happens): `Select * from all_objects where last_ddl_time > SYSDATE -1 order by last_ddl_time desc`. Among the list of objects, there should be your package as well, as it most probably has either been invalidated or compiled, for the given time period (since `SYSDATE -1`). Then, find which of those objects causes an implicit invalidation of your package (i.e. `PKG_MY_PACKAGE`) and eliminate the REAL problem, which causes this ORA error.

Comment: Then, at some point, the object that your package depends on gets compiled and Oracle implicitly recompiles your package, so the process continues. Since there isn't any changes on your package the problem IS NOT in your package, but in one of the dependent objects. Find out which one it is, find the owner of it (the developer) and fix the problem that this is causing.

Comment: Yes I agree. There is no control to monitor or re-compile the package from my application. So, I would like to handle in my application by re-try same method if i get exception. I know, that is not good solution, may be after 2 re-try I may get response. Here my question is, Can I create new connection for each re-try or within the same connection to re-try. I referred in stack-overflow, each connection has compiled object of stored procedure that's the reason,  i would like to close the connection and re-try with fresh DB conncetion. Which solution will be best. please suggest me